# Object-specific (Lead) Activity actions permissions

Tags: permissions, page-layout, leads, activities, global-actions

I am struggling to find the permission related to an issue with user-specific & object-specific activity functionality missing from the Lead record page for end-users only (not admin).

Activity actions (eg: email, log a call) have been added from "Mobile & Lightning Actions" onto the Lead page layout:

[image: Actions on lead layout]

Also, the 'Activity' lightning page component is added to the record page details as usual (same as Account, which I'll use as an example comparison moving forward, though it's not the only other object that's working as expected).

[![Activity timeline on lightning page, assigned as org default]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R6T0.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R6T0.png)

When I (sysadmin profile) visit the same Lead to the activities timeline, actions show up as expected (I'm able to see and click 'Email' button) at the top of the activities timeline.

[image: Lead page showing activity actions correctly under sysadmin login]

But my problem is that if any other user visits the same page, only the timeline loads WITHOUT activities available.

[image: Activities missing from end user Lead page]

Logged in as the same user, viewing an account instead of a lead, the activity actions show up as expected.

[image: Activities shown on Account record page for end user]

I've checked object & system permissions thoroughly (wide open CRUD w/ view-all and inherited public sharing for Lead & Task/Activities) before posting and have tried searching variations of verbiage to find this anywhere w/o any luck so far. I'm sure it's a simple setting in the permissions I've missed, especially given I'm able to see it w/ full sysadmin grants, but if anyone can point me in the right direction as to how I can make the activity actions available to the end user on the lead record page, it would be greatly appreciated!